# Using variables to direct output to different files

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use variables to direct program output to different locations based on some user config settings.

```
if [ -f "vars/debug.var" ]; then
   DUMP=''
else
   DUMP='&> logs/dump.log'
fi

...

ping -I eth0 -c 10 www.google.com $DUMP

...
```

So, if the file debug.var exists, DUMP is an empty string, but if it does not exist I want to pipe the output to the dump.log file.

I have tried a lot of different combinations of the variable and command and nothing has worked out... I keep getting the error

```
ping: unknown host &>
```

Anybody have an idea? Or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eval "ping -I eth0 -c 10 www.google.com $DUMP"
```

Comment: Huh? Now what if it has a space in its filename?

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko, it works when `DUMP='>& logs/my\ dump.log'`.

Comment: Hah, it's like not quoting your variables and blaming the user that it was his fault when he entered an asterisk in path. I'd better play on safe side.

Comment: So, where is the list of expressions that people should avoid when using your solution? For example, you have to escape ``;``, ``'``, ``"``, ``$``, ``<`` and many others...

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko, you are creating a problem where none exist. The OP's question was pretty simple, with none of the complexities you are trying to account for. Every solution does not have to be fool proof. We should find solutions that are no complex than they need to be.

Comment: No, mister. YOU are creating a potential problem by not quoting your variables. A simple search on your profile has revealed that you're unable to quote variables even in most obvious places. Basically all of your answers with ``bash`` tag are incorrect (most of them have quoting errors, but some answers are special!). Either read this to educate yourself http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls OR don't post your wrong solutions, please. I will give ``-1`` for every obviously wrong answer (so that you can improve them and notify me), but I think that SO will not allow me to give too many -1's.

Comment: You're in luck! It seems like stackoverflow allows to give maaany downvotes. I will indicate other answers as well, this time with comments, because this pack would be about other more complicated errors than just quoting. Feel free to write me a message when you finish editing them.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko, I am not sure what your mission is. I see that you have gone on a downvoting spree without any explanation of why. I have fixed some of those answers by quoting the variables but there are others where I don't think quoting is necessary. I hope it's helping you somehow.

Comment: I'm just improving your answers. If there is no explanation then it is a quoting error, search for it. For example consider this line ``command $(command $1 $(command $2))``, it should be quoted like this ``command "$(command "$1" "$(command "$2")""``. I will loop through your answers once again in a week and give +1 for every fixed answer. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing around with eval (which is a security hole)

```
if [ -f "vars/debug.var" ]; then
   : # nothing
else
   exec &> logs/dump.log
fi
ping -I eth0 -c 10 www.google.com
```

What exec does is allowing you to redirect output as needed, and you can do that in a sub-shell `(...)` as well to limit the scope of the re-direct.

Comment: +1, However, originally I thought that the point was to be able to change '&>' to something else via variable. Also, what if you want to log some commands but at the same time you want some other commands to print straight into stdout?

Comment: I like how clean this is, unfortunately there is other output that I need over stdout. This pipes all of my output to the dump file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another safer variant that allows you to have arbitrary paths.

```
DU='&>'
MP='logs/ * /du mp.log'
eval "xargs ping -I eth0 -c 3 www.google.com $DU \"\$MP\""
```

Or you can use an array:

```
DUMP=('&>' 'logs/ * /du mp.log')
eval "xargs ping -I eth0 -c 3 www.google.com $DUMP \"\${DUMP[1]}\""
```

And you can quote it like this to save 1 character

```
eval "xargs ping -I eth0 -c 3 www.google.com $DUMP "'"${DUMP[1]}"'
```